# JSF2.1.x does not work if there is space in the path. Error: Illegal character in opaque part at index 22

Tags: jsf-2, websphere, ibm-rad

My app has recently upgraded from JSF 1.2 to JSF 2.1.3.  I am using Mojarra.

My app is installed as an EAR through the WAS7 admin console in RAD8.

The index 22 is refererring the space in "Program Files".

When the server starts here is the error that matters that I get:

```
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in opaque part at index 22: wsjar:file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/SDP/runtimes/base_v7/profiles/IndSalesUtilsAppSrv02/installedApps/R8CMY8NW7LNode03Cell/IndUserServices.ear/IndUserServicesWeb.war/WEB-INF/lib/ind-jsf-v1.6.0.jar!/META-INF/faces-config.xml
    at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2809)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:2982)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3019)
    at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:578)
    at com.sun.faces.config.configprovider.MetaInfFacesConfigResourceProvider.loadURLs(MetaInfFacesConfigResourceProvider.java:160)
    ... 30 more
```

Here is the full stack trace:

```
[12/3/12 11:26:02:659 CST] 00000009 webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp notifyServletContextCreated SRVE0283E: Exception caught while initializing context: {0}
                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: javax.faces.FacesException: java.io.IOException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in opaque part at index 22: wsjar:file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/SDP/runtimes/base_v7/profiles/IndSalesUtilsAppSrv02/installedApps/R8CMY8NW7LNode03Cell/IndUserServices.ear/IndUserServicesWeb.war/WEB-INF/lib/ind-jsf-v1.6.0.jar!/META-INF/faces-config.xml
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:290)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:1708)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.commonInitializationFinish(WebApp.java:381)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:299)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:100)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:166)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:732)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:617)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:376)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1127)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1319)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:610)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:944)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:740)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2051)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:385)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:328)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$300(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$CUInitializer.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:895)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:349)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1613)
Caused by: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: javax.faces.FacesException: java.io.IOException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in opaque part at index 22: wsjar:file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/SDP/runtimes/base_v7/profiles/IndSalesUtilsAppSrv02/installedApps/R8CMY8NW7LNode03Cell/IndUserServices.ear/IndUserServicesWeb.war/WEB-INF/lib/ind-jsf-v1.6.0.jar!/META-INF/faces-config.xml
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.getConfigDocuments(ConfigManager.java:663)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:323)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:223)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: javax.faces.FacesException: java.io.IOException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in opaque part at index 22: wsjar:file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/SDP/runtimes/base_v7/profiles/IndSalesUtilsAppSrv02/installedApps/R8CMY8NW7LNode03Cell/IndUserServices.ear/IndUserServicesWeb.war/WEB-INF/lib/ind-jsf-v1.6.0.jar!/META-INF/faces-config.xml
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:222)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:83)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.getConfigDocuments(ConfigManager.java:649)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: javax.faces.FacesException: java.io.IOException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in opaque part at index 22: wsjar:file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/SDP/runtimes/base_v7/profiles/IndSalesUtilsAppSrv02/installedApps/R8CMY8NW7LNode03Cell/IndUserServices.ear/IndUserServicesWeb.war/WEB-INF/lib/ind-jsf-v1.6.0.jar!/META-INF/faces-config.xml
    at com.sun.faces.config.configprovider.MetaInfFacesConfigResourceProvider.getResources(MetaInfFacesConfigResourceProvider.java:135)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$URITask.call(ConfigManager.java:1179)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$URITask.call(ConfigManager.java:1148)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.getConfigDocuments(ConfigManager.java:639)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in opaque part at index 22: wsjar:file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/SDP/runtimes/base_v7/profiles/IndSalesUtilsAppSrv02/installedApps/R8CMY8NW7LNode03Cell/IndUserServices.ear/IndUserServicesWeb.war/WEB-INF/lib/ind-jsf-v1.6.0.jar!/META-INF/faces-config.xml
    at com.sun.faces.config.configprovider.MetaInfFacesConfigResourceProvider.loadURLs(MetaInfFacesConfigResourceProvider.java:177)
    at com.sun.faces.config.configprovider.MetaInfFacesConfigResourceProvider.getResources(MetaInfFacesConfigResourceProvider.java:108)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in opaque part at index 22: wsjar:file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/SDP/runtimes/base_v7/profiles/IndSalesUtilsAppSrv02/installedApps/R8CMY8NW7LNode03Cell/IndUserServices.ear/IndUserServicesWeb.war/WEB-INF/lib/ind-jsf-v1.6.0.jar!/META-INF/faces-config.xml
    at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2809)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:2982)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3019)
    at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:578)
    at com.sun.faces.config.configprovider.MetaInfFacesConfigResourceProvider.loadURLs(MetaInfFacesConfigResourceProvider.java:160)
    ... 30 more
```

Things I have tried that have not worked:

1. Updated to JSF 2.1.14 (looking at source of MetaInfFacesConfigResourceProvider I see it has not changed from 2.1.3 to 2.1.14, so that makes sense that it doesn't work.)
2. Get Source Code Import the app as a project
   (works if path to project does not have space, does not work if there is
   a space in the path to project)
3. Change the "Runtime Environment" on the Server from
   "C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7" to
   "C:\Progra~1\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7"  (doesn't seem to do anything)

I am pretty sure it is related to [this](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2057) issue, that never appears to get resolved

It would not surprise me if this is an IBM problem.  But I need to get this work somehow without IBM fix.

Reinstalling RAD8 in a new location that does not include a space is not an option at this time.

Comment: The issue report is indeed much related. It also confirms that it works in (old) Mojarra 2.0.4. Can you give it a try and confirm if it indeed works for you with 2.0.4, then one may be able to propose how to patch it for 2.1.14. Further, which JDK/JRE are you using? IBM or Oracle one? If IBM one, try Oracle one. By the way, reinstalling RAD in a new location was probably been a less time consuming approach than sitting back waiting for an answer.

Comment: Sorry..I was delayed with production issues and vacation over the past few weeks.   I was able to confirm that it works in 2.0.4.  Fails in 2.1.3, 2.1.14.  Works in 2.1.16 and 2.1.17.  So I will mark the answer from edburns.  I am pretty sure I am only using IBM.  I only have WebSphere and RAD 8.0.1 available to me at work.  Concerning waiting for an answer...I am afraid I needed to wait for a fix because we are using this solution with 30+ developers.  Updating the app is cheaper than updating 30+ workstations.  Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to have been fixed in 2.1.16 and 2.2 trunk.

http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2628

Comment: Yes...This fixed my issue exactly. Here is the issue  http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2628. Unfortuntely, now I am having the same problem with the faces-config.xml in WEB-INF of the app. But at least I am closer.

Comment: Version 2.1.28 appears to have fixed this issue and issue with faces-config.xml.

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
File f = new File("C:/Program Files/I...[rest of filepath]");
URI u = f.toURI();
```

to get your URI. Spaces are valid in filenames, but invalid in URI's, this will escape it properly.

Comment: How should the OP apply this "solution" to his case? Do you understand the concrete problem in any way?

Comment: Mojarra seems to be open source

Answer (score 0):

This problem is always present on IBM WAS 7/8 when I deploy a **war application** (inside an ear) and the war application **contain spaces** in the name.

My solution is to **remove every space** in the "war" filename.